# Is there a Certification requirement for device using mains power in/around water

Tags: mains, water

Is there a device certification requirement when using mains power (60hz / 120V) in/around water? I'd like to market a custom fish-tank with integrated lightbulb and pump. The lightbulb won't be submerged, but the product will place mains power and water in near proximity.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. I would advise the use of PVC enclosures for all the circuits. Even with an isolation transformer you want to shield all power feeds.

Comment: All mains powered new designs must be safety certified.  I would imagine you need a safety GFCI breaker and a titanium ground rod. https://www.marinedepot.com/Titanium_Ground_Probe_GFCI_Extension_Cords_Grounding_Probes_Surge_Protectors_for_Saltwater_Aquariums-TAAM_Via_Aqua-TA1111-FIMIGF-vi.html  Although you would be wise to use low voltage units

Answer (score 0):

You would want that kind of device to be galvanically isolated from the earth, preferably using isolated 1:1 transformer as an external power source. Isolated transformer is one that is not referenced to input ground.